# Как найти число, которое встречается во всех строках матрицы?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

> Задан целочисленный массив N*M (N - количество строк, M - столбцов). Каждая строка массива упорядочена по возрастанию. Требуется написать программу, которая находит число, встречающееся во всех строках.

Я подготовил решение, но не понимаю, как довести его до конца.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int func (int h,int length,int &arr[h][length],int height,int check)
{
  int otvet=0;
  for (int i=0;i<length;i++)
  {
    if (arr[height][i]==check)
    {
      otvet=1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (otvet==1 && height==(h-1)) return 1;
  if (otvet==1) return func(arr,height+1,check,length,h); else return 0;
}
int main()
{
  int y,x;
  cin >> y >> x;
  int arr[y][x];
  for (int i=0;i<y;i++)
  {
    for (int j=0;j<x;j++)
    {
      cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  for (int i=0;i<x;i++)
  {
    int b,ok;
    b=arr[0][i];
    ok=func(y,x,arr,i,b);
    if (ok==0) continue;
    else {
      cout << b;
      break;
    }
    if (ok==0) cout << "NO";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как я понял, нужна рекурсивная проверка каждой следующей строки, пока элемент текущей равен элементу предыдущей.

Comment: Так не понятно: хотите использовать алгоритм std::set_intersection или нет?

Comment: Нет, имею в виду сухой алгоритм без применения функций, его облегчающих

Comment: Так у вас уже есть псевдокод алгоритма и нужно написать код, или нужен алгоритм?

Comment: Нужно чтобы он заработал. Возможно здесь кроме ошибок есть очевидности, котрых я не вижу

Comment: @Max В C++ нет массивов переменной длины.

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите, как должно быть

Comment: Сдаюсь. "Нужно, чтоб он заработал" - алгоритм? код? Понятно, что нужно гулять по первым элементам строк, переходя к следующему элементу строки там, где он минимален... Но если у вас есть готовый псевдокод - то что я пытаюсь рассказывать? У вас же **уже** есть работающий алгоритм (что такое иначе *псевдокод*, как не описание работающего алгоритма?)

Comment: Короче нужно чтобы этот код заработал

Comment: Описал алгоритм, возможно он верный, возможно, нет. Как я только что понял, я на верном пути.

Comment: Во-первых, задания в стиле "Короче нужно чтобы этот код заработал" - это не для SO. Во-вторых, теоретически задача нахождения одного такого числа может быть проще задачи нахождения всех таких чисел. Вам точно нужно найти только одно?

Comment: @AnT первое (оно же наименьшее, так как по возрастанию в исходном массиве), или NO если такого не существует. Короче, самое первое число, которое есть во всех строках

Comment: @AnT Я исправил вопрос, мне важнее - понять, как работает рекурсия опираясь на этот пример, рекрсия - больная тема, к сожалению

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Пример программы на базе кода автора, с тем же алгоритмом (т.е. линейный поиск и рекурсивный спуск по строкам)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/*
 * Функция проверяет есть ли заданный элемент в заданной и последующих строках
 * На входе:
 *   arr - массив сортированных строк из целых чисел
 *   height - количество строк
 *   length - длина строк
 *   s - индекс заданной строки
 *   elem - искомый элемент
 * На выходе:
 *   true - если элемент присутствует во всех строках начиная с заданной
 *   false - заданного элемента в следующих строках нет
 */
bool func(int** arr, int height, int length, int s, int elem)
{
  // ищем элемент в строке:
  for (int i=0; i<length; ++i) {
    if (elem < arr[s][i])
      return false; // дальше все элементы больше, конец рекурсии
    else if (elem == arr[s][i]) { // нашли элемент
      if ((s+1) == height) // строка последняя, конец рекурсии 
        return true;
      else // а вот тут собственно и рекурсия:
        return func(arr, height, length, s+1, elem); // проверяем последующие строки тем же самым образом
    }
  }
  return false; // ничего не нашли, конец рекурсии
}

int main()
{
  int N,M;
  cout << "Lines:";
  cin >> N;
  if (N<2) return -1; // минимальная проверка размерности не помешает
  cout << "Columns:";
  cin >> M;
  if (M<1) return -1; // минимальная проверка размерности не помешает
  int** arr = new int*[N]; // массив строк
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    cout << "Line " << i+1 << ':';
    arr[i] = new int[M]; // инициализируем строки
    for (int j=0; j<M; j++) cin >> arr[i][j]; // заполняем столбцы
    // тут бы следовало проверить строку: отсортирована ли она, или принудительно сортировать
  }
  int i=0;
  // ищем элементы первой строки во второй и последующих
  while((i<M) && (!func(arr,N,M,1,arr[0][i]))) ++i;
  if (i==M) cout << "NO" << endl;
  else cout << arr[0][i] << endl;
  // подчищаем за собой
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) delete[] arr[i];
  delete[] arr;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

### Доработанный алгоритм, на базе бинарного поиска. Рекурсия уже по окну поиска в строке и по спуску на последующие строки. Плюс запоминание левых индексов окон поиска

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

/*
 * Функция проверяет есть ли заданный элемент в заданной и последующих строках
 * На входе:
 *   arr      - массив сортированных строк из целых чисел
 *   height   - количество строк
 *   length   - длина строк
 *   s        - индекс заданной строки
 *   elem     - искомый элемент
 *   lIndexes - массив индексов левых границ поиска в строках начиная со второй
 *              (индекс первого проверяемого элемента)
 *   right    - правая граница поиска
 *              (индекс элемента следующего за последним проверяемым)
 * На выходе:
 *   true     - если элемент присутствует в заданных границах поиска такущей строки
 *              и на всех строках начиная с заданной
 *   false    - заданного элемента нет
 */
bool func(int** arr, int height, int length, int s, int elem, int* lIndexes, int right)
{
  int left = lIndexes[s-1]; // для уменьшения времени доступа
  if (elem == arr[s][left]) { // искомое число найдено
    lIndexes[s-1] = left+1; // последующие числа следует искать со следующего индекса в этой строке
    if ((s+1) == height) // строка последняя, конец рекурсии
      return true;
    else { // проверяем следующие строки
      if (lIndexes[s] >= length) // следующая строка уже гарантированно имеет меньшие числа
        return false;
      else
        return func(arr, height, length, s+1, elem, lIndexes, length);
    }
  }
  if (elem < arr[s][left]) // число меньше всех в имеющихся в строке, выходим
    return false;
  if (elem > arr[s][right-1]) { // число больше всех в имеющихся в строке, выходим
    lIndexes[s-1] = right; // все последующие искомые числа также будут больше этого элемента
    return false;
  }
  if ((right-left) < 2) // в окне один элемент и мы его уже проверили, выходим
    return false;

  // уменьшаем окно поиска:
  int middle = left + (right - left) / 2; // новая граница окна поиска
  if (elem < arr[s][middle]) // новая граница справа
    return func(arr, height, length, s, elem, lIndexes, middle);
  else { // новая граница слева, сохраняем её и ищем дальше
    lIndexes[s-1] = middle;
    return func(arr, height, length, s, elem, lIndexes, right);
  }
  return false; // ничего не нашли
}

int main()
{
  srand ((unsigned)time(nullptr));
  int N,M;
  cout << "Lines:";
  cin >> N;
  if (N<2) return -1; // минимальная проверка размерности не помешает
  cout << "Columns:";
  cin >> M;
  if (M<1) return -1; // минимальная проверка размерности не помешает
  int** arr = new int*[N]; // массив строк
  int* lIndexes = new int[N-1]; // индексы левых границ окна поиска
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    if (i>0) lIndexes[i-1] = 0; // поиск начинаем с первых элементов
    cout << "Line " << i+1 << ':';
    arr[i] = new int[M]; // инициализируем строки
    int randValue = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<M; j++) { // заполняем столбцы
      //cin >> arr[i][j]; // слишком мучительно вручную это всё вводить...
      // вместо строки выше, формируем искусственный сортированный массив
      randValue += 1+std::rand() % 2;
      arr[i][j] = randValue;
      cout << randValue << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  int i=0, elem = arr[0][0]-1;
  // ищем элементы первой строки в последующих
  while(i<M) {
    if (elem != arr[0][i]) { // проверка на случай повтора предыдущего элемента
      elem = arr[0][i];
      if (func(arr, N, M, 1, elem, lIndexes, M)) break; // нашли число, выходим
    }
    ++i;
  }
  if (i==M) cout << "NO" << endl;
  else cout << arr[0][i] << endl;
  // подчищаем за собой
  delete[] lIndexes;
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) delete[] arr[i];
  delete[] arr;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: медленно. Тут скользящее окно надо. `Каждая строка массива упорядочена по возрастанию` существенно упрощает.

Comment: человек хотел довести код с рекурсией до работающего. Понятно что метод поиска в строке можно было бы оптимизировать, но я посчитал, что это усложнит восприятие кода рекурсивной функции

Comment: Ваше решение за `O(n*m)` работает?

Comment: Т.к. использован линейный поиск, да, сложность O(n*m). Без кардинальной переделки кода автора можно перейти внутри функции к бинарному поиску, тогда получим O(m*log(n))

Answer (score 3):

Если дано, что каждая строка уже заранее упорядочена по возрастанию, то (без использования рекурсии)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const unsigned N = 20, M = 20;
  int arr[N][M];

  // Подготовка входных данных

  for (auto &row: arr)
  {
    for (auto &e : row)
      e = std::rand() % 10;
    std::sort(std::begin(row), std::end(row));
    for (auto e : row)
      std::cout << std::setw(2) << e << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  // Собственно поиск

  unsigned i_pos[N] = {}, i_row;
  int value;

  for (; i_pos[0] < M; ++i_pos[0])
  {
    value = arr[0][i_pos[0]];
    // Будем искать это значение в остальных строках матрицы

    for (i_row = 1; i_row < N; ++i_row)
    {
      int test_value;

      for (; i_pos[i_row] < M; ++i_pos[i_row])
        if ((test_value = arr[i_row][i_pos[i_row]]) >= value)
          break;

      if (i_pos[i_row] == M || test_value != value)
        // В первом случае: значение не найдено - полный провал
        // Во втором случае: значение не найдено, но следует попробовать следующее
        break;

      // Значение найдено - переходим к поиску в следующей строке
    }

    if (i_row == N || i_pos[i_row] == M)
      // В первом случае: значение найдено - успех
      // Во втором случае: значение не найдено - полный провал
      break;

    // Значение не найдено, но следует попробовать следующее
  }

  if (i_pos[0] < M && i_row == N)
    std::cout << "Common value: " << value << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "No common value" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ваше решение за `O(n*m)` работает?

Comment: @hedgehogues: Да, за O(nm) в худшем случае и за O(n) в лучшем.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void intersect(vector<int> v, vector<vector<int>> a, size_t& n, vector<int>& r)
{
    if (++n >= a.size()) return;

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater<int>());
    sort(a[n].begin(), a[n].end(), greater<int>());

    vector<int> t(min(v.size(), a[n].size()));

    vector<int>::iterator i = set_intersection(v.begin(), v.end(), a[n].begin(), a[n].end(), t.begin(), greater <int>());
    r.resize(0);
    for (vector<int>::iterator j = t.begin(); j != i; j++)
        r.push_back(*j);

    intersect(r, a, n, r);
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> a = { { 1,2,3,18},{ 4,3,5,18 },{ 7,8,3 } };
    vector<int> r(a[0]);
    size_t n = 0;
    intersect(a[0], a, n, r);

    for (vector<int>::iterator j = r.begin(); j != r.end(); j++)
        cout << *j << ";";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваше решение за `O(n*m)` работает?

Comment: Оценочно. На практике чуть быстрее из за сортировки. STL при этом оптимизирует поиск. Так что это самый быстрый способ. Заниматься самому тем, что делает STL, оптимизируя поиск отсортированного, слишком накладно.

Comment: Это решение работает намного медленнее, чем O(mn) из-за странных ненужных копирований данных и сортировок. Если избавиться от ненужных действий, то работать будет за О(mn), но накладные расходы в худшем случае все равно будут велики.